# Is this loop method correct? Python 3.4.3

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, location

So, I wanted a set of XY positions that would be different to each other. In order to do this, I had used a list to store the variables XY, which were randomly generated. If the position was not in the list, it would be added to it, and if it were in the list, then it would remake a position for it.

I am unsure if this will work in all instances, and wonder if there is a better way of doing this.

```
import random

positionList = []

for i in range(6):
    position = [random.randint(0,5),random.randint(0,5)]
    print("Original", position)
    while position in positionList:
        position = [random.randint(0,5),random.randint(0,5)]
    positionList.append(position)
    print(position)
```

Could the remade position be the same as other positions in the list?

Comment: by the way, Python 3.0 is really deprecated. The Python3.x development has been at 3.4 for *years*

Comment: @Slayer Hi, and no. I just want 6 different XY positions

Comment: making `positionList = set()` would remove a linear lookup, are you sampling once or many times? You will also need to use tuples to add to the set

Comment: So would I need to convert each of the positions into tuples?

Comment: `pos = random.randint(0,5),random.randint(0,5)`  `if pos not in pos_set`. `pos_set.add(pos)`  in place of your append

Comment: Ok, like this?
http://pastebin.com/dXCajs5d

Comment: @ProMCKingz, I just added an answer showing you how

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks, marked as solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Could the remade position be the same as other positions in the list?*

Yes, because you are using random. If you want to be sure that you are preserving the unique items you can use a `set` object for that aim which preserve the unique items for you. But note that since lists are not hashable objects you should use a hashable container for pairs (like tuple):

```
>>> position_set = set()
>>> 
>>> while len(position_set) != 6: 
...     position = (random.randint(0,5), random.randint(0,5))
...     position_set.add(position)
... 
>>> position_set
set([(3, 2), (5, 0), (2, 5), (5, 2), (1, 0), (3, 5)])
```

Comment: Not mine but try `set([(0, 0), (4, 5), (4, 2), (0, 0), (3, 4), (0, 0)])` ;) The point of the while is to get 6 unique pairs

Comment: @PadraicCunningham So what's the problem with that? the result would be `>>> set([(0, 0), (4, 5), (4, 2), (0, 0), (3, 4), (0, )])
set([(4, 5), (4, 2), (0, 0), (3, 4), (0,)])` But note that `(0,)` is invalid in this case.

Comment: lol it definitely would not be `set([(0, 0), (4, 5), (4, 2), (0, 0), (3, 4), (0, )]) `, do sets have dupes?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Set comprehension doesn't guarantee that the length of set is always 6. Check out the update :).

Comment: Yep, that was the point I was trying to make ;) +1 for seeing the light

Comment: Thanks, a much shorter method.

Comment: So what would happen if i added another variable called position2, and wanted that to be different to position1 values?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need lists, you can convert, if not just leave the code as is:

```
import random

position_set = set()

for i in range(6):
    position = random.randint(0, 5), random.randint(0, 5)
    print("Original", position)
    while position in position_set:
        position = random.randint(0, 5), random.randint(0, 5)
    position_set.add(position)
    print(position)
print(position_set)
```

A set lookup is `O(1)` vs `O(n)` for a list, since order seems irrelevant just use a set altogether is probably sufficient.

Comment: No worries, you can just loop until the length is 6 as per kasra's code, I just left the code as similar as possible to your own

Answer (score 0):

To be sure of 6 different elements, you can use `random.shuffle` :

```
from random import shuffle

all=[(x,y) for x in range(5) for y in range(5)]
shuffle(all)
print(all[:6])

"""
[(0, 1), (3, 4), (1, 1), (1, 3), (4, 3), (0, 0)]
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

I just run your code, and it seems to work pretty fine. I believe it is correct. Let's consider your while loop.

You check if the randomly generated 'position' is already in the 'positionList' list. The mere statement:

```
position in positionList
```

returns either True or False. If the 'position' already appears in your list, the while loop gets executed. And you simply calculate another random position.

The only advice I could give is to add a loop counter. When you run out of possible XY positions, the loop runs forever.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it

```
import random

    my_list =[]
    num_of_points = 6 

    while True:
        position = [random.randint(0,5),random.randint(0,5)]
        if position not in my_list:
            my_list.append(position)
            print num_of_points
            num_of_points -=1
            if (num_of_points == 0):
                break

    print my_list
```

of course you just need to make sure that the number of possible random pairs exceeds the num_op_points value.